# Same variable name inside function as globally. Any problems? Is this good style?

Tags: r, function

In R, is there any issue with writing a function which takes some parameters, and then when we need to call the function, we define some variables with the same name as those parameters, and then we call it on those variables?

```
f <- function(name) { return(name) }
name <- S
f(name)
```

I do this with all my functions.

Comment: Structurally it's fine, but stylistically as code gets more complicated I find it to be useful to name them differently so I don't accidentally pull in a variable from a broader environment or otherwise introduce bugs without noticing.

Answer (score 1):

There is no "issue" in that things will work just fine. Each function get's it's own execution scope. Values set inside a function will not be seen outside that function by default. Naming variables is more a matter of style.